# Python classes no attribute error

Tags: python, class

I wrote this class:

```
class Bmi(object):

    def __init__(self,regel):
        self.persoon = regel
        self.lengte = []
        self.gewicht =[]

    def parse_input(self,regels):        
        for regel in regels:
            lengte = regel.split('\t')[2]
            gewicht = regel.split('\t')[3]
        self.lengte = lengte
        self.gewicht = gewicht
        return self.lengte, self.gewicht
```

I want to use it to parse input that looks like this, to get the length and weight of each person:

```
Dean Johnson    M   1.78    83
Sophia Miller   V   1.69    60
```

My program looks like this:

```
from ipy_lib import file_input
from BMI import Bmi

bestand = file_input()
for i in bestand:
    Bmi(i)
    i.parse_input()
```

I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'parse_input'. 
What goes wrong here and what does the error mean?

Comment: `bmi = Bmi(i); bmi.parse_input(...)` ?

Comment: that works. But now i get this error: TypeError: parse_input() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: what is the bestand variable content?

Comment: The bestand content is the two persons and their gender, length and weight. as shown in the thread

Comment: Any separator between rows?

Comment: no seperators between rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about use standard python to solve your input problem?

```
from BMI import Bmi
with open('path.to.file') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        bmi = Bmi(line.split("\t")[0]) #pass the person's name
        bmi.parse_input(line)          #pass all the line, and parse_input will do the stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` *is* a string. What else would it be? It's a character from the user input.

Your code takes that string, instantiates a Bmi object with it, and then immediately throws that object away and tries to call parse_input on the original string.

Instead you should assign the Bmi to a new variable, and call parse_input on that instead.

Comment: could you give an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As falsetru said, you think you are calling the `parse_input` method on a `Bmi` object, but you're actully calling it on `i`, which is a string.

You probably would prefer to do that this way :

```
from ipy_lib import file_input
from BMI import Bmi

bestand = file_input()
for i in bestand:
    bmi = Bmi(i)
    bmi.parse_input(i)
```

Comment: when i do it like that i get this error:TypeError: parse_input() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I edited my answer, `parse_input` takes two parameters : `self` and `regels`. `self` is the object on which the method is called, you don't need to pass it as a parameter. I suppose `regels` is the string which the `Bmi` object parses, so in this case you need to call `bmi.parse_input(i)`.